# Python requests-html with drop-down list selector

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am performing a scrape on a site which contains a java script to retrieve data and a drop-down list input. I am using requests-html to deal with the java part, but I am struggle to select the value in the drop down.

Here is my code:

```
import requests_html
import bs4
url = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/stir/eurodollar_quotes_settlements_futures.html'
params = {'tradeDate':'01/15/2019'}
session = requests_html.HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url, params=params)
r.html.render()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.html.html, 'lxml')
r.session.close()
x = soup.body.find('select', attrs={'id':'cmeTradeDate'})
```

Output is the bs4.element.tag:

```
<select class="cmeSelect" id="cmeTradeDate" name="tradeDate" style="width: 268px; padding-right: 60px;"><option selected="" value="01/16/2019">Wednesday, 16 Jan 2019 (Final)</option> option value="01/15/2019">Tuesday, 15 Jan 2019 (Final)</option><option value="01/14/2019">Monday, 14 Jan 2019 (Final)</option><option value="01/11/2019">Friday, 11 Jan 2019 (Prelim)</option><option value="01/10/2019">Thursday, 10 Jan 2019 (Final)</option></select>
```

As you can see, the selected value in the drop-down is the 16th Jan, even though I specified the 15th. The futures data in the main table is also for the 16th.

The code to extract the table was nice and simple with pandas:

```
pd.read_html(r.html.html, attrs={'id':'settlementsFuturesProductTable'})[0]
```

How can I select the date from the options before extracting the html?

(Also, side note, if requests-html can do the same thing as I'm using BeautifulSoup for then I would love to know how.)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the page you're interacting with relies heavily on javascript, which `requests` does not evaluate. Passing `tradeDate` as a `GET` parameter does nothing with this particular site. You are better off interacting with the endpoint it's pulling the data from, as follows:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Futures/Settlements/1/FUT'

r = json.loads(requests.get(url, params={
    'strategy': 'DEFAULT',
    'tradeDate': '01/15/2019',
    'pageSize': '500'
}).text)

print(f"tradeDate: {r['tradeDate']}")

for settlement in r['settlements']:
    print(settlement)
```

Result:

```
tradeDate: 01/15/2019
{'month': 'FEB 19', 'open': '97.2875', 'high': '97.3025', 'low': '97.2875', 'last': '97.2975', 'change': '+.0125', 'settle': '97.2975', 'volume': '80,470', 'openInterest': '216,090'}
{'month': 'MAR 19', 'open': '97.3100', 'high': '97.3250', 'low': '97.3000', 'last': '97.3150', 'change': '+.0150', 'settle': '97.3200', 'volume': '239,375', 'openInterest': '1,440,528'}
{'month': 'APR 19', 'open': '97.3050', 'high': '97.3250', 'low': '97.3000', 'last': '97.3200', 'change': '+.0150', 'settle': '97.3200', 'volume': '17,317', 'openInterest': '41,199'}
...
```